# vim + tmux visual mode not highlighting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, tmux

When I run vim in `tmux`, the syntax highlighting works fine except for the visual mode, it works but doesn't change the colors of the selected text, which I find quite annoying.

The problem stays the same even when I switch the colorscheme(I am currently using molokai)
I have the option set t_Co=256 on my vimrc
My .tmux.conf file is the same as the t-williams.conf example(just added the line "set -f default-terminal "xterm"")

I already tried some solutions to problems related to the 256 color support

any tips?

Comment: The recommended setting for tmux is `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` and you don't need `set t_Co=256` in your `~/.vimrc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recommended setting for tmux is

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

and you don't need

```
set t_Co=256
```

in your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: On my end, need to add this in `.vimrc` also: `set term=xterm-256color`, so my `.tmux.conf` still has `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`. Setting them both as `xterm-256color` or `screen-256color` didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your terminal declares itself as a 256 color supported terminal (for example, `xterm-256color`). This will set the `TERM` in bash, which is read by tmux, and will automatically set the `default-terminal` setting to `screen-256color`.

For example, in the Terminal on OS X you can change this in the settings under the "Advanced" tab. The "Declare terminal as" option:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem but I checked my `TERM` variable and it is well set to `screen-256color`.